# Как правильно настроить ConnectionStrings?

Tags: c#, sql

У меня есть строка подключения:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Host=localhost;Server=DESKTOP-JCNQMTB\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Db"
  }
```

Но эта строка подключения работает только на моем компьютере. Буду очень благодарен, если кто-то подскажет, как сделать ее универсальной, т.к. как не экспериментирую, не получается. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Вместо localhost используйте ip своего компа. Также настройте сервер БД, чтобы он мог принимать подключения с интерфейсов, отличных от 127.0.0.1, по умолчанию он не принимает.

Comment: Сделать строку подключения, чтобы она работала на всех компьютерах, фактически, невозможно. Потому её и не делают константой в коде, а выносят в конфиг: чтобы можно было легко поменять при переносе на другой компьютер.